# Customize Angular Bootstrap datepicker popup buttons

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to customize the default buttons in Angular Bootstrap datepicker popup. Currently I have [image: this]
What I want is a space of around 1(or 2)px between the blue and green buttons. The green button should remain the same(both space in between wise and size wise).

Currently, there are a lot of code and I have no idea about where the CSS files are located. Also, there for all the code in the project, the same thing is being observed and the change has to be made for all such occuring cases.
I have tried to make changes in the `bootstrap\less\button-group.less` file:

```css
.btn-group {
  .btn + .btn,
  .btn + .btn-group,
  .btn-group + .btn,
  .btn-group + .btn-group {
    margin-left: 1px;
  }
}

.btn-group-vertical {
  > .btn,
  > .btn-group,
  > .btn-group > .btn {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }

  // Clear floats so dropdown menus can be properly placed
  > .btn-group {
    &:extend(.clearfix all);
    > .btn {
      float: none;
    }
  }

  > .btn + .btn,
  > .btn + .btn-group,
  > .btn-group + .btn,
  > .btn-group + .btn-group {
    margin-top: -1px;
    margin-left: 1px;
  }
}
```

And in `bootstrap\distcss\bootstrap.css`

```css
.btn-group .btn + .btn,
.btn-group .btn + .btn-group,
.btn-group .btn-group + .btn,
.btn-group .btn-group + .btn-group {
  margin-left: 1px;
}
```

But nothing happens. The rendering still happens with margin left of -1px.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Maybe you know this, but you should never modify the library's files. For css/less you can easily override the styles from within your own files. Just use the same selector (e.g. `.btn-group .btn + .btn { ...}`). Your files normally are loaded after the library files, so it will automatically override the original version.

Comment: To find out why it's not working, inspect the elements in your browser (usually the shortcut is CTRL-SHIFT-i). In the style inspector you then can check which styles are considered for the given element and which ones are actually applied.  (more info on https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/)

Comment: @johey I am seeing that in the inspector, the properties that I changed are not reflected back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the templates at the github repo, the specific template for the Datepicker-Popup you can [find here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/template/datepickerPopup/popup.html).

You can copy it and make your own customized copy and link it to the directive using the `datepicker-template-url` attribute

I recommend just in-lining the margin css style over your custom template and be done with it